# How to shift audio track without delay in AS2

Tags: flash, audio, actionscript-2, shift

I have written an application that plays 2 audio tracks in Flash.
Now is my problem: how to make so, that after user have pressed a key, second track would be shifted(forwards/back)?
This action and then playing should be without additional caching and delays.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just play them separately, and delay the start of the second one? Or are you trying to do it as they are already playing?

Comment: 2 tracks must be played at once, the second - shifted(after user have pressed a key)

Answer (score 0):

A very interesting question. You want to realize something like a player, where you can shift a second track and then play this two tracks simultaneous. Is it correct?

Comment: Try to set the arguments of the play method like in the example:
This example shows how to create a playlist on the server:
 // Create a NetStream for playing
 var my_ns:NetStream = new NetStream(my_nc);
 my_video.attachNetStream(my_ns);
 
 // Play the stream record1
 my_ns.play("record1", 0, -1, true);
 
 // Switch to the stream live1 and play for 5 seconds.  
 // Since reset is false, live1 will start to play after record1 is done.
 my_ns.play("live1", -1 , 5, false);

Look at the help to the NetStream class http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/NetStream.html